# Defaulting currency pipe to value in angular

Tags: angular

I am using currency pipe in my Angular application. I need to default it to `GBP` when there is no value. As you can see the currency symbol is based on `legal?.company?.corporateCreditReport?.creditLimit?.currency` which would contain `GBP` or `USD` for example. How do I default it to have `GBP` in the pipe

```html
    <span>{{
          legal?.highestTransactionValue
            | currency
              : legal?.company?.corporateCreditReport?.creditLimit?.currency
              : 'symbol'
              : '1.0-0'
        }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```html
<span>
  {{ legal?.highestTransactionValue | currency: ((legal?.company?.corporateCreditReport?.creditLimit?.currency)? legal.company.corporateCreditReport.creditLimit.currency : 'GBP'): 'symbol': '1.0-0'}}
</span>
```